# RabbitMQ custom exchange (script-exchange installation trouble)

Tags: python, rabbitmq, message-queue, publish-subscribe, amqp

By default when I send a message with absent routing_key, the broker rejects it. How can I force RabitMQ to send one to the some 'default' queue? For example, I have 3 consumers with keys 'con1', 'con2' and 'con4'. I send a message with the key 'con3' and I need broker requeues message to some 'starter' queue that can start 'con3' consumer and requeue message again?

I found this https://github.com/tonyg/script-exchange and I sure it helps me, but I can't install it because the repository updated 4 years ago and modern umbrella dev kit is not support this old makefile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's necessary to use a combination of the [alternate exchange](http://www.rabbitmq.com/ae.html) protocol extension and the [consistent-hash exchange plugin](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-consistent-hash-exchange). So, you should declare 2 exchanges: direct and x-consistent-hash (alternative to the first one). Then all existing consumers should create their own queues bounded to the direct exchange. In this case all messages with routing keys of 'con1', 'con2' and 'con4' will be routed directly to the consumers whereas messages with another routing keys will be rerouted to the alternative exchange which can route them to the some 'managers', which starts the necessary processors (consumers).

The 'script-exchange' RabbitMQ plugin is unsupported now.